# React: sending FormData to the server returns {}

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch

I have some FormData that I would like to fetch to a post url.

```
const data = new FormData(e.currentTarget); //form currentTarget
data.set("file", file)
data.append("description", editorState.blocks[0].text)

e.preventDefault();

await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DR_HOST, { //http://localhost:3000/
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
}).then(res =>
{
    console.log(res)
    // window.location = res.url;
})
```

After sending the data, `console.log(req.body)`  I get in return **{}**, `console.log(req.body.get("file") //or anything else instead of file)` returns nothing.

**server.js** middlewares:

```
server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));
```

I have tried multiple solutions but in the end the result remains the same **{}**. How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: can you share code of controller

Comment: @abhipatil **console.log(req.body) 
    console.log(req.body.get("title")) 
    const title = req.body.get("title")
    const description = req.body.get("description")
    const file = req.body.get("file")

    const declarationSchema = Joi.object({
        title: Joi.string().required(),
        description: Joi.string().required(),
        file: Joi.string()
    })

**

Comment: add a try/catch to the controller. Do a console.log(req.body) in the try block and set a breakpoint there. You maybe hitting an error or you need to add app.use(express.json())

Comment: @cWerning I also tried a lot of solutions including express.json() but nothing new from what I have tested. Wrapping everything inside try and catch returns only this error: `TypeError: req.body.get is not a function`

Comment: that is beacuse `req.body.get` does'nt exists try without get `req.body`

Comment: @abhipatil there is no error returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Component:

```
e.preventDefault();
const data = new FormData(e.currentTarget);

data.append("file", JSON.stringify(file))
data.append("description", JSON.stringify(editorState))

await fetch(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DR_HOST, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: body,
            // headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
        }).then(res =>
        {
            // window.location = res.url;
        })
```

Controller:

```
router.post('/', upload.single('file'), async (req, res, next) =>
{
//rest of the stuff
```

I forgot to add the multer upload middlware before the specific function.